# Collapse directories in zsh prompt in a unique way

Tags: zsh, prompt, pwd

Is there a way to collapse the current working directory in the zsh prompt in a unique way, so that I could copy and paste it to another terminal, hit TAB and get the original path?

Let's say we have following directories:

```
/adam/devl
/alice/devl
/alice/docs
/bob/docs
```

If the prompt is programmed to show the first characters, and I'm in /b/d, then it is unique. On the other hand, /a/d is not unique, so I would need /ad/d, /al/de and /al/do. And even /ali/… as soon as the user alex appears.

Is it possible to hack this directly in zsh or do I need to write a script, that finds the shortest unique beginning of each parent directory?

Thank you for your ideas!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not aware that `zsh` has a built-in function of this sort, but it should be pretty easy to script without resorting to a single subshell or slow pipe:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

paths=(${(s:/:)PWD})

cur_path='/'
cur_short_path='/'
for directory in ${paths[@]}
do
  cur_dir=''
  for (( i=0; i<${#directory}; i++ )); do
    cur_dir+="${directory:$i:1}"
    matching=("$cur_path"/"$cur_dir"*/)
    if [[ ${#matching[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
      break
    fi
  done
  cur_short_path+="$cur_dir/"
  cur_path+="$directory/"
done

printf %q "${cur_short_path: : -1}"
echo
```

This script will output the shortest path needed for auto-completion to work.

You can throw it in your `.zshrc` as a function and then run it from any directory.

```bash
function spwd {
  paths=(${(s:/:)PWD})

  cur_path='/'
  cur_short_path='/'
  for directory in ${paths[@]}
  do
    cur_dir=''
    for (( i=0; i<${#directory}; i++ )); do
      cur_dir+="${directory:$i:1}"
      matching=("$cur_path"/"$cur_dir"*/)
      if [[ ${#matching[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        break
      fi
    done
    cur_short_path+="$cur_dir/"
    cur_path+="$directory/"
  done

  printf %q "${cur_short_path: : -1}"
  echo
}
```

Here's a video of it in action:

https://asciinema.org/a/0TyL8foqvQ8ec5ZHS3c1mn5LH

Or if you prefer, some sample output:

```
~/t $ ls
adam  alice  bob  getshortcwd.zsh

~/t $ ls adam
devl

~/t $ ls alice
devl  docs

~/t $ spwd
/h/v/t

~/t $ cd adam/devl

~/t/adam/devl $ spwd
/h/v/t/ad/d

~/t/adam/devl $ cd ../../alice/devl

~/t/alice/devl $ spwd
/h/v/t/al/de

~/t/alice/devl $ cd ../docs

~/t/alice/docs $ spwd
/h/v/t/al/do

~/t/alice/docs $ `spwd` [TAB]
~/t/alice/docs $ /h/v/t/al/do [TAB]
~/t/alice/docs $ /home/vsimonian/t/alice/docs
```

Comment: Thank you, it works in my prompt like a charm. What resource would you recommend to get a good overview of the zsh syntax?

Comment: Probably the most comprehensive resource you'll find is [The Z Shell Manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/), the official reference. It's where I go to whenever I want to dig into syntax, and I often skim through it to understand certain syntaxes better. There's also the [user guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.html), which is a bit more of a learning experience than a reference, though I'm sad to say it hasn't been completed. But it's a good getting-started resource, if not a bit wordy and unformatted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to collapse the directories to a first-unique-letter path and have the Z Shell expand that path upon pressing [Tab].  I simply used compinstall (zsh utility script installed with Zsh) to generate the following code.  The important part to take note of for expanding path elements is on the **sixth `zstyle` command, near the end**, where the bracket of characters to separate completion points with includes the `/`, which is, of course, the directory separator. With this, the unique paths you suggested will fully fill out with just one [Tab] press as if the `*` were at the end of each path-name unique letters.

```
# The following lines were added by compinstall

zstyle ':completion:*' add-space true
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _list _expand _complete _ignored _match _correct _approximate _prefix
zstyle ':completion:*' completions 1
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]} r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'm:{[:lower:]}={[:upper:]} m:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]} r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'r:|[._-/]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' match-original both
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/micah/.zsh/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall
```

As for creating the unique path in the first place and inserting it into the prompt, it is possible with a zsh script or function, and therefore *should* be possible for the completer or line-editor also, but just sticking to the prompt, you would add a function to the `$precmd_functions` array that modifies or adds to the `PS1` variable.  This special array is a list of function names that are run right before each prompt.

```
function precmd_unique_pwd {
  local pwd_string="$(upwd)"
  PS1="%B%n@%m $pwd_string => %b"
}
precmd_functions+=( precmd_unique_pwd )
```

For getting of the current PWD in shortened form, I think this function is clear and easy to follow, though not necessarily optimized for low resource usage.

```
#!/bin/zsh
function upwd {
        emulate -LR zsh -o nullglob
        local dir Path
        local -a newpwd tmp stack
        local -i length=1 Flag=0
        newpwd=( ${(s./.)PWD} )
        foreach dir ( $newpwd )
                (( length=0, Flag=0 ))
                repeat $#dir
                do
                        (( length += 1 ))
                        tmp=( ${(j.*/.)~stack}/$dir[1,$length]*(/) )
                        if
                                (( $#tmp == 1 ))
                        then
                                Path=$Path/$dir[1,$length]
                                stack+=( /$dir )
                                (( Flag=1 ))
                                break
                        fi
                done
                if
                        (( Flag ))
                then
                        continue
                else
                        Path=$Path/$dir
                fi
        end
        print -- $Path
}
upwd
```

Notice that it finds unique paths with directory names because of the Zsh feature `(/)` at the end of the globbing. On the last directory (current) this means you may match something else if there is a file with the same name plus an extension.